# How to use Sinon to stub a call which makes a REST request

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to get my bearings with sinon and mocha and I have the code and test below. I'm trying to test the `findAll()` method without actually making an http request anywhere.

With the current code I get the error `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined]`. I'm not sure how to stub or spy the `.on` event.

/modles/user.js

```
'use strict';

const Rest = require('restler');
const Q = require('q');

class User {

  static findAll() {
    return Q.promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      Rest.get('<SOME URL FOR DATA>')
      .on('complete', function(data, response) {

        if(data instanceof Error) {
          return reject(data);
        }

        return resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
...
}

module.exports = User;
```

/test/models/user.js

```
'use strict';

const expect = require('chai').expect;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const Rest = require('restler');

describe('User model', function() {

  var User;

  beforeEach(function() {
    this.get = sinon.stub(Rest, 'get');
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    Rest.get.restore();
  })

  it('should not blow up when requiring', function() {
     User = require('../../models/user');
     expect(User).to.not.be.undefined;
  });

  describe('findAll()', function() {
    it('should return all users', function() {

      const expected = [{personId: 1234}, {personId: 1235}];

      User.findAll()
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log('result = ', result);
      })
      .fail(function(err) {
        console.log('err = ', err);
// KEEPS DISPLAYING THIS: err =  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined]
      })
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: That's because `Rest.get(...)` returns nothing.

Comment: try replacing the " .on('complete'," with ".then",
Let me know if it worked. And please post the content of "require('restler')"

Comment: `.on` is correct. https://github.com/danwrong/restler

Comment: @zerkms can you help me with the correct solution then?

Comment: I can give you more hints: what should `Rest.get()` return? How do you use `sinon` to set a pre-defined return value?

Comment: Rest.get() emits an event `.on('complete'` and that callback function should contain `[{personId: 1234}, {personId: 1235}]`.

Comment: "emits an event" --- that's wrong: it returns an object. So you should return an object.

Comment: According to the documentation here https://github.com/danwrong/restler#api it returns an object which emits an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously mentioned, `Rest.get()` returns `undefined` whereas the `findAll` method requires it returns an `object` with an `on` property of type `function`. With sinon, you could control what values a stub returns when invoked by using the `stub.returns` API. You also need to ensure, the callback passed to the `on` method gets invoked. You can achieve this by using the `stub.yields` API.
If you need to be strict and also validate the position of the callback attached, use `stub.callsArgWith(1, expected)`

**Example**

```
describe('findAll()', function() {
  it('should return all users', function() {
    const expected = [{personId: 1234}, {personId: 1235}];
    Rest.get.returns({
      on:sinon.stub().yields([expected])
    });
    User.findAll()
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log('result = ', result);
    });
  });
});
```